# How to query 2 seperate things within the same SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to return the values of both Metric 447 and 615 however because the 447 will return in the QSA.NumValue and the 615 will return in the QSA.DateTimeValue. I need it return when they are populated so if it is 615 then don't allow DateTimeValue to be NULL and if 447 then don't allow NumValue to be NULL because a simple OR statement will not work when included in the WHERE statement.

Is this possible?

```
  SELECT
  Q.ID
  ,Q.Title
  ,QS.ID
  ,QSA.QMID
  ,QSA.NumValue
  ,QSA.DateTimeValue
  ,QM.MetricID
  ,S.Date
FROM
  QSA
  INNER JOIN QM
    ON QSA.QMID = QM.ID
  INNER JOIN QS
    ON QSA.SessionID = QS.ID
  INNER JOIN Q
    ON QS.ID = Q.ID
  INNER JOIN SQ
    ON Q.ID = SQ.ID
  INNER JOIN S
    ON SQ.ID = S.ID
WHERE
  QM.MetricID IN (447, 615)
  AND QSA.DateTimeValue IS NOT NULL
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is wrong with this SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may looking for this

```
WHERE
    1=CASE WHEN QM.MetricID = 447 AND QSA.NumValue NOT NULL THEN 1
           WHEN QM.MetricID = 615 AND QSA.DateTimeValue IS NOT NULL THEN 1
           ELSE 0
      END
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following `WHERE`:

```
WHERE
  (QM.MetricID = 447 AND QSA.NumValue IS NOT NULL)
  OR (QM.MetricID = 615 AND QSA.DateTimeValue IS NOT NULL)
```